# Typescript types do not pass through custom function properly, but do work when calling class directly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following setup, where I want to use TypeScript to make sure the user is only choosing types that are allowed in the interface.

This works fine if I call the class directly, but if I use a custom generic function to pass back same class function it does not work and gives an error.

Can anyone help me understand how to fix this?

```js
export interface IMyInterface {
  test1: {
    test1Sub: {
      test1SubSub: string
    }
  },
  test2: {
    test2Sub: {
      test2SubSub: string
    }
  }
}

export default class MyClass<T> {
  parentFunction = <A extends keyof T>(app: A) => (
    {
      childFunction: (page: keyof T[A]) => {
        console.log(app, page)
      }
    }
  )
}

// simplified for example
export function useMyCustomHook<T> (app: keyof T) {
  const settings = new MyClass<T>();
  return settings.parentFunction(app)
}

// Works when calling class directly
const myClass = new MyClass<IMyInterface>()
const parent = myClass.parentFunction('test1')
const child = parent.childFunction('test1Sub')

// does not work when calling via hook
const myHookValue = useMyCustomHook<IMyInterface>('test1')
myHookValue.childFunction('test1') // ERROR - Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

I have created a playground example of this.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFkBPfFNLXOAbwCg45UBnGARgC4b6HHgXWAygFcARpzo8ezNsJGzOLKMgDm3BgF9u6gDTdpAJnFreLffK6SGB2ecUrjmjbU21QkWHAAmwLEIA28Nh+mExMcCQAwsGhADwAKgB8FnBgmFDAKABiQkjYMAgQSHAAvHAxAIJwoKhInmEA1sDEEOhwiQAUmGBgnOUAlCVJ7cYSltgAFgh+ntm5+YWc7anKwJyNza1xANrlALoDxUmjlnDYhUwQfsAAdH4Qyp3d2imYK33GTpKOcO8uAPR-OBMBAAWzAfgQ6AQwE8cHQ0CqIEwYKurnA0Hg6ByeQKRSETGAkXxMAgIIAEhAIPV4kMuj04OsWm0BqMzkgWEDgDB8khlGFSkhgAB3cLEKIhJg09p9ADc3HSMCEUCKBO5KiY11S6Sy2PmSEeYF+tFoALgAHVoPUwkLxhlTpg-BDeV4EOk8n5iLQ2RyQWLovy4IKRZF-TEiKRyBgcMAEtKved4FqMvBSr7xaFNWlk7McYV2gByaSsfPvb2BSbTEovbUwa4TKYzXW4gtF2Ql42mzwQPiBiDwIWWuA2u3YB1O5RwABuCEwcHGlPq8fZ8F9FKpADUHUI8KV8YSxcTSWvqeGyKgo7hY4W+Gx26uF5u-Nu6xXG3Nm9f+CWgA)

Comment: Type inference is defining the type of the `childFunction` argument as never. I think you need to define a return type of the useMyCustomHook and define a non generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an explicit type for the app parameter:

```
export function useMyCustomHook<T, A extends keyof T>(app: A) {
  const settings = new MyClass<T>();
  return settings.parentFunction(app);
}

const myHookValue = useMyCustomHook<IMyInterface, "test2">("test2");
myHookValue.childFunction('test2Sub')
```

This is because without extending `keyof T`, inside the scope of `useCustomHook` the parameter `app` will always be treated as the widest type `keyof T`. When you use it with `childFunction` that creates a function signature of:

```
childFunction: (page: keyof T[keyof T]) => {
  console.log(app, page)
}
```

The type `keyof T[keyof T]` on `MyInterface` resolves to an intersection of two string literal types `"test1Sub"` and `"test2Sub"`, which is always `never`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  I am not keen on having "test2">("test2"), is there any way to remove "test2" from the parentesis and just have it in the type instead?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because you need an actual runtime value to pass to `parentFunction`, and you can't remove `"test2"` from the type parameters either since combinations of explicit and inferred type parameters are not allowed.

The only way to clean it up would be by changing the signature to `useMyCustomHook<T, A extends keyof T> (obj: T, app: A)` so both types can be inferred. Then you could call it with an actual runtime object which matches the interface like `useMyCustomHook(obj, "test2")`.

Comment: That’s a shame, I don’t have an object of that instance type unfortunately, this is what the hook is getting for me. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it

Comment: @user3284707 see the edit - I actually got the logic slightly the wrong way round, you do not need to type the inner function again, you just need to extend your parameter.